# How do I find the coordinates of this point, and then the area?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling w the wording of this question (been stuck for 15+mins).

'The line $3x -4y = 8$ meets the $y$-axis at $A$. The point $C$ has coordinates $(-2,9)$. The line through $C$ perpendicular to $3x - 4y = 8$ meets it at $B$. Calculate the area of the triangle.'

Comment: calculate the line which is perpendicular to $3x-4y=8$

Comment: It certainly is convenient that $\Delta ABC$ is a right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a poorly worded question.  I'll rephrase it.**  You may not need help with the math, if the question is worded better.

Original:

> The line 3x -4y = 8 meets the y-axis at A. The point C has coordinates (-2,9). The line through C perpendicular to 3x - 4y = 8 meets it at B. Calculate the area of the triangle.

Understandable wording:

> There are three points we will call A, B, and C.
>
> Point A is the place where the line $3x -4y = 8$ meets the y axis.
>
> Point C has coordinates $(-2,9)$.
>
> The line through point C that is perpendicular to the line $3x - 4y = 8$, meets that line at point B.
>
> Calculate the area of triangle ABC.

The last clue could also be phrased:

> Point B is somewhere on the line $3x - 4y = 8$.  Line BC is perpendicular to the line $3x - 4y = 8$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what i understood is: The point $A$ is the intersection of the line with the y axis. $A=(0,-2)$, the point $C$ for hypothesis is $(-2,9)$. And the point B is a point where it can form a perpendicular line to $3x-4y=8$ and intersects with the point $C$.

 
First you find the slope of the line $3x-4y=8$ is $m=\frac{3}{4}$, then the slope of the perpendicular line is $m=-\frac{4}{3}$ (
Remember that two lines are perpendicular if the product of their slopes is -1). Using the equation of the line, we need the line intersects with the point $C$ then:
$$(x+2)\left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)=y-\frac{3}{4}$$
This is the equation of the perpendicular line, and the intersection with the given line is at the point $(4,1)$ (Verify). Now, we have a triangle with coordenates $(4,1),(-2,9), (0,-2)$. As the line connecting point (4,1) with the point (-2,9) forms a right angle with the given line, the triangle is a right triangle. The only thing you need make is find the distance of the point (4,1) to (0,-2) and the distance from the point (4,1) to (-2,9) and use the area formula of triangle.

Answer (score 0):

from the given equation we get $$y=\frac{3}{4}x-2$$ and the other line is given by $$y=-\frac{4}{3}x+n$$ since $C(-2,9)$ fulfills this equation we obtain $$n=\frac{19}{3}$$ and now you can calculate the coordinaters of $B$

Answer (score 0):

You have the slope of the given equation  $= \frac{3}{4} $.  So the perpendicular line will have the slope $=\frac{-4}{3} $ using this slope with point $C $ to get the equation of the perpendicular line $3y=-4x+19$ now sole the two equations together to get point $B=(4, 1) $ Now you have the 3 coordinate $A, B, C$. You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a picture of the situation.  I was looking for another way to find the area, but I don't think you can avoid the work of calculating the coordinates of point $ \ B  \ $ using what you've learned before calculus.

What you are given which is important is that side $ \ BC \ $ is perpendicular to side $ \ AB \ $ .  **Refaat M. Sayed** and **sango** have obtained the coordinates of $ \ B \ $ as $ \ (4 \ , \ 1 ) \ . $  What is "cute" in this problem (and was probably intended to save you a bit of work) is that the difference in the $ \ x-$ coordinates of points $ \ A \ $ and $ \ B \ $ is $ \ 4 \ $ and the difference in their $ \ y-$ coordinates is $ \ 3 \ $ .  So $ \ \overline{AB} \ $ is the hypotenuse of a  $ \ 3-4-5 \ $ triangle.  Similarly, the differences in the $ \ x-$ and $ \ y-$ coordinates of points $ \ B \ $ and $ \ C \ $ are $ \ 6 \ $ and $ \ 8 \ , $ respectively.  Thus $ \ \overline{BC} \ $ is the hypotenuse of a $ \ 6-8-10 \ $ triangle.  The right triangle $ \ \Delta ABC \ $ consequently has area $ \ \frac{1}{2} · 5 · 10 \ = \ 25 \ \ . $

Further along in your courses, when you learn about vectors, there are slick ways to get the area of $ \ \Delta ABC \ $ with and *without* finding the position of $ \ B \ $ .